# How to insert data from one table to another using transactions in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is table where I want to insert data

```
group_id  | customer_id 
-----------------------
3         |  14
3         |  8
4         |  14
```

To insert one value code would be like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO results(group_id INT, customer_id INT)
    VALUES(4, 12)
COMMIT;
```

What is the correct way to insert multiple customer_id values that I get from complex select statement? Can it be done like this? Maybe it is better to insert data in local temporary table and only then insert in results table?

```
DECLARE @group_insert INT;
SET @group_insert = 5;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO results(group_id INT, customer_id INT)
    SELECT @group_insert, customer_id  ---actual select would have more joins and where conditions
    FROM another_table
    WHERE customer_id > 10
COMMIT;
```

Results table should look like this after insert:

```
group_id  | customer_id 
-----------------------
3         |  14
3         |  8
4         |  14
5         |  15
5         |  16
5         |  17
```

Comment: Create one SELECT statement which selects **all** rows to be inserted, and insert them all in **one** INSERT statement. And none transaction and iteration needed.

Comment: Why does 14 not appear in the result given you are testing WHERE customer_id > 10 - does this test (as well as  @group_insert) also change every time you run and do you intend to manually change your code before you run it? BTW you cannot declare user defined variables and you cannot DECLARE variables unless in a stored program(procedure,function,trigger,event) ALSO don't give variables the same name as colums.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for comment. To clarify I am inserting additional data in "results" table. There is no example of "another_table" that is used in select statement. @ group_insert is set manually before running script and it doesn't change during transaction, @ group_insert is the same for all customer_ids that are inserted in one transaction. (This is how I want it to work)

Comment: @Akina Why would it be better without Transaction?

Comment: *Why would it be better without Transaction?* Single statement is a transaction itself. So explicit transaction is simply excess.

Comment: You didn't clarify WHERE customer_id > 10 - is this always going to be the same every run?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, this is just example, there is quite complex select with many joins and where clauses using declared variables that gets me specific customer_ids. Basically select statement doesn't change, but it uses different pre defined variables.

Comment: Your `INSERT . . . SELECT` is fine.  There is no need to wrap it in an explicit transaction, if that is the only operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @group_insert INT;
SET @group_insert = 5;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO results(group_id , customer_id )
    SELECT @group_insert, customer_id  
    FROM another_table
    WHERE customer_id > 10;
COMMIT;
```

If you want to select `group_insert` column from `another_table` then:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO results(group_id , customer_id )
    SELECT group_insert, customer_id  
    FROM another_table
    WHERE customer_id > 10;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I can't see the difference between this code and the OPs published code?

Comment: Data type should not be in insert into statement.

Comment: Datatypes in OP's statement looks like datatype markers, not as a part of the query...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have oversimplified but as a guess here's a code which disallows duplicate cids in another table and a procedure which works out the next id for insert and the min cid for input deduping as it goes.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;

CREATE TABLE T (ID INT,CID INT);
CREATE TABLE T1(CID INT PRIMARY KEY);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P()
BEGIN
 SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID),0) + 1 INTO @NEXTID FROM T;
 SET @MAXCID = NULL;
 IF @NEXTID = 1 THEN
    SET @MAXCID = 0;
  ELSE
    SELECT MIN(CID) INTO @MAXCID FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT CID FROM T WHERE T.CID = T1.CID);
 END IF;
 
 IF @MAXCID IS NOT NULL THEN
  INSERT INTO T
    SELECT @NEXTID,CID
     FROM T1 
     WHERE CID >= @MAXCID;
 END IF;
 
     
END $$
DELIMITER ;
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
TRUNCATE TABLE T1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO T1 VALUES (1);
CALL P();


INSERT IGNORE INTO T1 VALUES (2),(3);
CALL P();


INSERT IGNORE INTO T1 VALUES (2),(3),(4),(5);
CALL P();

 MariaDB [SANDBOX]> select * from t1;
+-----+
| CID |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
+-----+
5 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [SANDBOX]> select * from t;
+------+------+
| ID   | CID  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    4 |
|    3 |    5 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```